# How to analyze a ruby error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, logging, error-handling

C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop>rake routes
(in C:/Users/Vlad/Desktop)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2482:in `const_missing'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:TaskLib>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<module:Rake>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:4:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:2:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb:12:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb:12:in `block in <class:TestUnitRailtie>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `call'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `block in load_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `load_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:396:in `block in load_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:396:in `load_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `load_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
C:/Users/Vlad/Desktop/kindle/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Can you walk me through the logic of why these lines appear in the console? I'm not interested in a particular error. When something messes up and I see a log like this, what does it mean?

Does the FIRST error say something critical about why the program broke down? If an error is really vague, what is a general logic I should look for in the error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lines are just backtrace of exception
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html#method-i-backtrace

also you can run commands with --trace flag